# Doctrine: Fill column with random values

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I want to update one column for all rows in a table with a random number. As far as my research goes, there is no rand() in Doctrine by default. The options I see are 1. Add a custom DQL-Function, this would be MySQL specific, 2. Update every row with a PHP generated value.

Both options seem like bad practice to me. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: or 3. Use native query. How often do You need to execute this query? How big is You table?

Comment: It's executed every day. Table has around 1k rows, but is growing. Native Query would mean a dependency on a specific database as a custom DQL-function would do aswell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with native query. It is much simpler than creating custom DQL function.

```
$em = getEntityManager();
$tableName = $em->getClassMetadata('Your:Entity')->getTableName();
$em->getConnection()->exec('UPDATE '.$tableName.' SET column=RAND()');
```

But if You prefer DQL go with it.

But doing it in PHP will be the worst.

- You will have to fetch all records first
- You will have to update each row one by one

Database is not something You change every week so don't be afraid of using vendor specific functions.